# Fail configuration , when Use Camera2 createCaptureSession on Raspberry pi 3 Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Current my device Raspberry pi model 3 on Android Things (Oreo 8.1)

first I try camera device open, and clicked capture button, 
get camera preview jpg file.

my source

```
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder;

private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

   @Override 
   public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }
   ...
}

private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    //camera open ...
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(320, 240, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
}

//Camera preview check
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }
    ...

};

//create a new CameraCaptureSession for camera preview
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
   try {
       SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
       assert texture != null;

       // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                 mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSesssion;
                 updatePreview();
             }

             @Override
             public void onConfiguredFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
             }
          }, null);
     } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
     }
 }
```

this source is success camera preview and camera capture on SamSung galaxy 8 device.

but raspberry pi 3 not open camera preview and fail capture.

raspberry pi always call `onConfigureFailed` on createCameraPreviewSession.

log

```
 W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:372: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
 E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
```

so I changed this part

```
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
```

--> change

```
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
```

this source is camera open on raspberry pi. but not work capture.

How to camera preview capture on raspberry pi 3 android things?

if you know please advice me

thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I'm using SurfaceView instead of TextureView. If I try to capture a photo OR preview, it works, but if I Try to do both actions on the same CaptureSession it doesn´t work.

Comment: I found this in Logcat  
2018-10-11 17:33:39.646 175-243/? E/V4L2CameraHAL: setupStreams:362: V4L2 only supports 1 stream configuration at a time (stream 0 is format 34, width 1280, height 720, stream 1 is format 33, width 320, height 240)  
2018-10-11 17:33:39.646 175-243/? E/Camera: configureStreams:0: Failed to setup stream set  
2018-10-11 17:33:39.646 175-243/? E/Camera3-Device: Camera 0: configureStreamsLocked: Set of requested inputs/outputs not supported by HAL