# Android Things - Creating a Camera Preview Session Fails, and no Preview is shown

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera2, android-things

I am trying to deploy the Android TensorFlow-Lite Example, specifically, the Detector Activity.

I have had success in deploying it in a Tablet. The app works great, it is able to detect objects, put a bounding rectangle around it, with a label as well as a confidence level.

I then set up my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Board, installed Android Things in it, connected via ADB, and then deployed the same program from Android Studio. However, the screen I was using for my Rπ board was blank.

Upon checking a [Camera Demo For Android Things tutorial](https://github.com/weichen2046/CameraDemoForAndroidThings), I had this idea to enable hardware acceleration in order to support the Camera Preview. I added in:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in the `application` tag of the Manifest.

I also added in the following within the application tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />
```

And an intent filter in my activity tag:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

So that the TensorFlow App runs after boot.

I deployed the application again, but the same error persists -- I am unable to configure the preview screen session.

Here is the following code that was included in the TensorFlow Example:

```
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        final SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        final Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        LOGGER.e("Opening camera preview: " + previewSize.getWidth() + "x" + previewSize.getHeight());

        // Create the reader for the preview frames.
        previewReader =
                ImageReader.newInstance(
                        previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);

        previewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageListener, backgroundHandler);
        previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewReader.getSurface());

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                Arrays.asList(surface, previewReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == cameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            previewRequestBuilder.set(
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            previewRequestBuilder.set(
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                            captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                                    previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
                        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                            LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
                            LOGGER.e("camera access exception!");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                        LOGGER.e("configure failed!!");
                    }
                },
                null);
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.e("camera access exception!");
        LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    }
}
```

The error log is the one that is in the `onConfigureFailed` override method, and the relevant error logs leading towards that statement are:

```
11-12 14:02:40.677 1991-2035/org.tensorflow.demo E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
11-12 14:02:40.679 1991-2035/org.tensorflow.demo E/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: configure failed!!
```

However, I couldn't trace the `Session 0:` stack trace.

Aside from turning on hardware acceleration and adding several other tags to the Manifest, I have not tried anything.

I have done my research and I have seen other examples, but they only take a photo at the click of a button. I need a working cameraPreview.

I also have that CameraDemoForAndroidThings example, but I'm afraid that I don't know a lick of Kotlin to be able to guess how it works.

If there's any one who managed to make a Java version of the TensorFlow Detection Activity run on Raspberry Pi Android Things, kindly contribute and let us know how you did it.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, the camera can only support one stream configuration at a time. I was also able to infer that I have to modify the `createCaptureSession()` function to only use one surface, my function now looks like this:

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
//                    Arrays.asList(surface, previewReader.getSurface()),
        Arrays.asList(surface),
        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                // The camera is already closed
                if (null == cameraDevice) {
                    return;
                }

                // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                try {
                    // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
//                                previewRequestBuilder.set(
//                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
//                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                    // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
//                                previewRequestBuilder.set(
//                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                    // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                    previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                    captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                            previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);

                    previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewReader.getSurface());

                } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                    LOGGER.e("exception hit while configuring camera!");
                    LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                LOGGER.e("Configure failed!");
                showToast("Failed");
            }
        },
        null);
```

This enables me to get a live preview. However, the code does not proceed with sending the image from the preview to the `processImage()` block.

Has anyone successfully implemented the TensorFlow-Lite examples that involve live Camera Previews to Android Things?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997776/camera2-api-error-failed-to-create-capture-session and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300315/fail-configuration-when-use-camera2-createcapturesession-on-raspberry-pi-3-and#comment92459793_51300315. The bottom line is, be careful with session configuration. Make sure you find a self-compatible set of parameters before you add TensorFlow to the brew.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have updated my question. I think I have been successful in creating a camera preview, but am stuck with proceeding to sending the preview to the part where TensorFlow-Lite processes the preview.

Comment: If you only have one (preview) surface, you don't receive pixels to send for processing. You need two, but make sure that they work together. See *[Setting multiple ImageReader surfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308362/android-camera2-api-setting-multiple-imagereader-surfaces-gives-blank-output)*

Comment: If TensorFlow Lite needs multiple surfaces, and the Android Things can only give process one preview surface at a time, is there a work around? Maybe allow TensorFlow to process the single surface? I am not well versed in these kinds of applications.

Comment: Sorry I did not express myself well. You need *previewReader.getSurface()* to *setOnImageAvailableListener()*. But parameters of this surface should be compatible with the camera and with the preview display. See the tables at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration) for the constraints of such settings for different device 'levels'.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get a solution to this issue?
Apparently I'm stuck with this same error and I'm unable to figure out a solution to this problem!