# Android camera2 api. Setting multiple ImageReader surfaces gives blank output

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I have a camera2 implementation. The current setup is, it uses a texture view surface to display the actual camera view and an `ImageReader` surface for capturing images.

Now I want to capture preview frames as well. So I tried adding a new `ImageReader` surface for capturing frames. But when I add that surface to `createCaptureSession` request, the screen goes blank. What could possibly be wrong? Below is the code that I use to add surfaces to `createCaptureSession`

```
val surface = preview.surface
            ?: throw CameraAccessException(CameraAccessException.CAMERA_ERROR)

val previewIRSurface = previewImageReader?.surface
            ?: throw CameraAccessException(CameraAccessException.CAMERA_ERROR)

val captureSurface = captureImageReader?.surface
            ?: throw CameraAccessException(CameraAccessException.CAMERA_ERROR)

try {
    val template = if (zsl) CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG else CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW

    previewRequestBuilder = camera?.createCaptureRequest(template)
            ?.apply { addTarget(surface) }
            ?: throw CameraAccessException(CameraAccessException.CAMERA_ERROR)

    val surfaces: ArrayList<Surface> = arrayListOf(surface, previewIRSurface, captureSurface)

    camera?.createCaptureSession(surfaces, sessionCallback, backgroundHandler)

} catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
    throw RuntimeException("Failed to start camera session")
}
```

The initialization of ImageReaders is like this.

```
private fun prepareImageReaders() {

    val largestPreview = previewSizes.sizes(aspectRatio).last()

    previewImageReader?.close()

    previewImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
            largestPreview.width,
            largestPreview.height,
            internalOutputFormat,
            4 // maxImages
    ).apply { setOnImageAvailableListener(onPreviewImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler) }

    val largestPicture = pictureSizes.sizes(aspectRatio).last()

    captureImageReader?.close()

    captureImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
            largestPicture.width,
            largestPicture.height,
            internalOutputFormat,
            2 // maxImages
    ).apply { setOnImageAvailableListener(onCaptureImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler) }
}
```

**More clarifications about the parameters used above:**

- `internalOutput` format is either `ImageFormat.JPEG` or `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`.
- Image sizes are based on best possible sizes
- It works good with either of the image readers individually but as soon as I add both together, blank screen!
- Testing on Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android Oreo (8.0)

*The original code is here https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex/blob/development/cameraViewEx/src/main/api21/com/priyankvasa/android/cameraviewex/Camera2.kt*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**maxImages == 4** may be too much and exhaust your RAM. Also, it's not clear what **internalOutputFormat** you use, and whether it is compatible with the **largestPreview** size.

The bottom line is, study the long list of tables for supported surface list parameter of [createCaptureSession()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)). Depending on your camera capabilities, the three surfaces that you use, could be too much.

From the comments below, a working solution: *"The error itself doesn't say much [...] but upon searching, it is found that multiple surfaces are not supported for JPEG format. Upon changing it to YUV_420_888 it works flawlessly."*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alex. I will add clarifications about all of that in the original post. The `internalOutputFormat` is `ImageFormat.JPEG`, I also tried with `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` but same result. Also `maxImages = 4` is safe in this case because I only request next frame once I am done with current one. Both the image readers work individually if I don't use the other one. But together it is just blank screen. I wonder if the device is relevant. If so I am testing on `Samsung Galaxy S8` with Android 8.0

Comment: As Alex says, there are limits to how many simultaneous outputs you can add to a capture session.  There should be errors in either the session creation or when submitting the first capture request, so try checking if any capture errors are being reported to your app.  Or if the capture session creation is returning an error callback.

Comment: @EddyTalvala thanks for pointing me to exceptions. The error itself doesn't say much `Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:434` but upon searching, it is found that multiple surfaces are not supported for JPEG format. Upon changing it to `YUV_420_888` it works flawlessly.

Comment: Yes, jpeg is the king of image formats. I mean, there may be only one jpeg in capture session, or none.

Comment: This is super useful! I have edited some of these comments into the answer because it solved the problem for me.