# Camera 2 API to Preview, Record and Extract the preview frame to Firebase face detection processing simultaneously

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camera2

My use case is when user start recording video, I need to record video and also process the preview frames for user face inside the frames using Firebase face detection. I have tried to do it following way but some preview is paused.

I am using [googlesamples/android-Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) codebase and I have added following code inside it.

Inside `Camera2VideoFragment` class:

```
private ImageReader mYUVImageReader;
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnYUVImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

   @Override
   public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Log.d(Camera2VideoFragment.TAG, "Bipin - onImageAvailable ");
   }
}
```

Inside `openCamera` method:

```
mYUVImageReader = ImageReader
                    .newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth()/16, mPreviewSize.getHeight()/16,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
            mYUVImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                    mOnYUVImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Inside `startRecording` method:

```
   Surface imageSurface = mYUVImageReader.getSurface();
   surfaces.add(imageSurface);
   mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(imageSurface);
```

I have tried to set `imageSurface` inside startPreview as well but no luck, Facing the same preview still issue. Please provide your input or correct me about what is the best approach for this scenario?

Demo app code here: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/Camera2Demo/tree/bipin

Updated:[10-Jan-2019]
I have renamed it to mYUVImageReader, Please find details here: 
Init: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/Camera2Demo/blob/bipin/app/src/main/java/com/camerademo/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L477
Adding ImageReaderSurface here: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/Camera2Demo/blob/bipin/app/src/main/java/com/camerademo/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L540

*My main concern is, Does it possible to provid output to the Preview surface (mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()), Recording (mMediaRecorder.getSurface()) and Continuous Image (mYUVImageReader.getSurface()) simultaneously by using Camera 2 API?*

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the new ImageReader Surface to the capture session creation as well.  You can't include a Surface in a capture request builder unless it was included in the session as well.

There are also limits on how many simultaneous outputs can be set up at once, and at what resolutions.  These are dependent on the supported hardware level and camera device capabilities.  See the docs for [createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) for those tables.

Comment: I have called the ImageReader surface `onConfigured` of `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback` class. Now, I am facing different error like this: ```01-09 13:17:02.634 19387-19406/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
    Process: com.camerademo, PID: 19387
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!```

Comment: I have pushed my demo app code here: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/Camera2Demo/tree/bipin

Comment: I don't see mRawImageReader anywhere in that code. The code in Camera2VideoImageActivity looks fine at first glance in terms of including mImageReader where it's needed in session creation.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, It's there, I have updated the question with the proper links.

Comment: Please provide your feedback about `Camera2VideoFragment` class. I have all the test code is there.

Answer (score 0):

See *[Android camera2 api. Setting multiple ImageReader surfaces gives blank output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308362/android-camera2-api-setting-multiple-imagereader-surfaces-gives-blank-output)* and comments there.

The code there is essentially correct, except *Ryan* tried to set capture format to **JPEG**: this cannot work, but **YUV_420_888** can work.
Another issue is that this won't work for LEGACY camera.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the YUV_420_888 but still, the preview is freezing. I found a list of devices hardware categories as you mentioned. http://www.tobias-weis.de/projects/camera2probe/

Comment: You don't need an external list to check whether your device must support multiple surfaces for a capture session. Also, note that the table you linked, is result of querying the camera API — therefore, I expect there to be quite a few inconsistencies, API reporting false answers.

Comment: Hi, Do we have any limit on the number of Surfaces we can add? Because I am not getting any error in logs. Preview is freezing only.

Comment: Yes, the number of surfaces, their formats and evensong sizes are limited. The tables in [createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) reference shows some of these limitations. Unfortunately, some unsupported cases don't produce reliable logs